# How do I find the location of the gem?

Tags: ruby, path, rubygems

I'm developing a library that provides access to gem metadata, including it's location on the file system. The idea was to let gem authors set it to a relative path from any script:

```
# $root/example.gemspec
Example::Gem.root '.'        # => $root/

# $root/lib/example/gem.rb
Example::Gem.root '../..'    # => $root/
```

Then, the path of the current script would be used to compute the absolute path. My implementation is currently as follows:

```
def root(relative_to = nil, file = __FILE__)
  unless relative_to.nil?
    @root = File.expand_path relative_to, File.dirname(file)
  end
  @root
end
```

I thought `__FILE__` would return the path to the caller's script, but that assumption is wrong.

It worked within the library itself, but broke down when I tried to integrate it with one of my other gems; the generated path was always relative to the support library itself.

How can I implement this without having to pass the current `__FILE__` on every call? Otherwise, there isn't much value to be gained; writing `root('../..', __FILE__)` is almost the same as writing an actual method to do the same thing.

If it's possible to figure out the path without having to specify *anything*, that would be even better, but I couldn't think of anything. How does Rails do it?

By the way, I'm aware of [`Gem::Specification#gem_dir`](https://github.com/rubygems/rubygems/blob/master/lib/rubygems/specification.rb#L1620), but it always returns paths relative to the installation directory, even if the gem is not actually there, which makes it useless in a development environment.

Comment: A place to start is working with `caller.first` and mangling the string as required. I'm not sure if there's a better version of same.

Comment: @tadman, isn't the the output of that method implementation defined? Anyway, I'll look it up.

Comment: @tadman, your solution works! I'm not sure if there are any gotchas, but from what I read [in the documentation](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Kernel.html#method-i-caller), it does just what I need. Add a proper answer so that I can accept it!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can always make use of the backtrace facility provided:

```
caller.first
```

It produces an amalgam of file and line but is usually separated by `:`. I'd be careful to allow for filenames or paths that may contain colon for whatever reason by ignoring the line information but preserving the rest. In other words, do not `split` but `sub`:

```
caller.first.sub(/:\d+:in .*$/, '')
```

Comment: Thanks for the heads up! [Just patched my code](https://github.com/matheusmoreira/jewel/commit/91beef313532ead964f20190557027099972f3b5). I used `/:\d+(:in .*)?\z/` since the documentation states `caller` may return strings in either the `file:line` or the `file:line:in method` format.